# shell - How to get value from json reponse with jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl, jq

I need to get "mxa.mailgun.org" with jq in bash

json response from curl request to api:

```
{
 "domain": {
    "created_at": "Sun, 13 May 2018 09:48:21 GMT",
    "id": "5af809e51f4b8b00011ee1aa",
    "name": "leadedign.co.uk",
    "require_tls": false,
    "skip_verification": false,
    "smtp_login": "postmaster@leddesign.co.uk",
    "smtp_password": "07d1dee-43f1869c",
    "spam_action": "disabled",
    "state": "unverified",
    "type": "custom",
    "web_prefix": "email",
    "web_scheme": "http",
    "wildcard": false
  },
  "message": "Domain DNS records have been updated",
  "receiving_dns_records": [
    {
      "cached": [
        "1 leadeesign.co.uk"
      ],
      "priority": "10",
      "record_type": "MX",
      "valid": "unknown",
      "value": "mxa.mailgun.org"
    },
    {
      "cached": [
        "1 leaesign.co.uk"
      ],
      "priority": "10",
      "record_type": "MX",
      "valid": "unknown",
      "value": "mxb.mailgun.org"
    }
  ]
  }
```

I tried :

```
curl -X PUT -s --user 'api:key-1659e3c0faff2c4e96e4' -G  https://api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/leadereign.co.uk/verify -d skip=0 -d limit=3 | jq '.[] | {receiving_dns_records: .[]}'

        curl -X PUT -s --user 'api:key-165903eaff2c4e96e4' -G  https://api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/leaderfeign.co.uk/verify -d skip=0 -d limit=3 | jq '.[] | {receiving_dns_records: .[value]}'
```

ps. domain and api key is changed for security reasons. this curl request wont work.

Comment: Please fix the JSON. It looks like you just want the first .value in the array. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You want the "value" value of the *first* "receiving_dns_records" item:

```
jq -r '.receiving_dns_records[0].value'
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solved it. I've been struggling with this almost a day.

Comment: Yeah, `jq` is a functional language. I'm still wrapping my brain around the complicated stuff.